# Обработка больших данных

Tags: php, sql

Допустим мне нужно прочитать CSV файл содержащий 20 000 наименований продукций + еще весит такой файл порядка 50МБ. Как можно открыть такой файл средствами php и выполнить около 20 000 sql запросов.

Увеличивать время выполнения скрипта? Если только это, то можно полный список со всеми настройками для php: время, увеличения памяти и тд.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам импорт csv файла в базу сделать нужно? тут в большинстве случаев можно напрямую - и быстро, и безопасно.

Comment: у меня fopen больше 2.5 МБ не открывает, както смущает дополнительно увеличивать память, да и на хосте наверное она тоже не резиновая?
+еще запросы. ведь прежде чем добавить новую продукцию нужно сделать проверку есть ли она в каталоге, если есть добавить, если нет то обновить информацию, которая идет в CVS.
тоесть из 20000 данных у меня на выходе получается как минимум 40000 запросов в БД, что меня сильно смущает

Answer (score 3):

Если вы запускаете данный скрипт из командной строки, то ограничений на время выполнения нет.

Для снятия ограничений по памяти используйте

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

Comment: а как запустить из командой строки и если не трудно можно полный список для работы тяжелых процессов: память, время и еще чтото если есть 

Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вот так: `php /path/to/your/script.php`

А насчёт ограничения потребляемых ресурсов - кроме памяти и времени выполнения нет других настроек.

Answer (score 0):

а данные в таблице есть уникальные? Я к тому что может есть возможность использовать INSERT с выражением  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?

я загружаю в инет магазин прайсы от поставщиков, так как прога предоставленная разработчиками не устраивала - медлено работала и тупила, я на локальном хосте с помощью php парсю файлы (xls, csv, xml) - а потом составляю из отфильтованных данных запросы по 500 строк , коннектюсь к базе и выполняю их. Скорось меня устраивает -25 тыщ записей вместе с парсингом одного файла выполняются в пределах 30 сек. Сервак находитсяна расстоянии 6000 км

Comment: Ну хорошо, это уменьшить запросы на половину было 20000 и будет 20000, но все таки есть способы работать с большими файлами и большим кол-во запросом, чтобы можно было обрабатывать 400, 500 и более МБ CSV файлы с 20,30,50,100,200 тыс. наименований продукций без ограничений и без последствий на хостинг? хотябы алгоритмы чтоб копать в какую-нибудь в сторону.

спасибо за ответ, любые ответы делают меня только умнее :)